# How do i change color on dinamically created divs by selecting 3 divs and double click to change color on the third div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am coding in jquery. I need help with double click in jquery. 
the divs are created dynamically and the thing is that I cannot find anywhere on how I can select 2 or 3 dynamically created divs and double click on the third div to change color. in total all 3 selected divs should change colors.

hope someone can help med solve this problem :)

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div>
    <label>
        <input id="numberOfDivs" type="number">
    </label>
    <input id="createBtn" type="button" value="Generate">
</div>

<div id="divWrapper"></div>

<script src="script/jquery-3.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Script.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#createBtn").click(function(){
var counter = 1;
var values = $("#numberOfDivs").val();
for(i = 0; i < values ; i++){
    var $div = $("<div>"  + counter +  "</div>")
        .css({"width": "50px", "height": "50px","background-color": "red", "margin": "5px", "float": "left"
    })
      .attr({
        class: "dClones"

    $("#divWrapper").append($div);
    counter++;
}

$(".dClones").bind("dblclick", function(){
   $(this).css({"background": "purple"})
});
});
```

Comment: share some relevant code

Comment: just posted my code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of toggling a class and untoggling.

```
$('body').on('dblclick','.dClones', function() {
  var me = this;
  if (!$(me).hasClass('css-double')) {
    $(me).addClass('css-double');
  } else {
    $(me).removeClass('css-double');
  }
});
```

You only need to use .on once for it to work for all dynamic and statically placed .dClones.

Alternative to cLass is .css but you'll have to know what styles to add and to revert to.

Comment: when i single click on some divs and they have changed their color and i double click on div again, but this time on a div that have not changed color. so those div changed color on single click should be change their color when i double click. is it possible to make this happen?

Comment: You only want one to change color at a time? So if one changes colors via double click you want the next one to be double clicked(without a color) to be the only one with a new color?

Comment: sory for my bad English :).  let's say that i have generated 12 divs and single click on 3 divs out of 12 divs. when i double click on a div that i have not clicked on it yet. should make all 3 three divs that were single clicked on change their color and the one double clicked on.

Comment: Okay so you'll have two kinds of actions. You'll be selecting divs, and you'll be double clicking to mark the  selected divs a different color?

Comment: yes. that's what i want. is it a way for doing exactly that?

Comment: Yes. In your single click event add a class to the divs Ex: `s-clicked`. Make sure that your single click event cannot fire if the element firing the click has the class `s-clicked` by checking it's class via `if ( ! $(this).hasClass('s-clicked') ) { $(this).addClass('s-clicked'); }`. Then on your `dbl-click` event select the single clicked elements. `$('.s-clicked')` and do what you want with them. Simple. :)

Comment: Glad to hear. Take care.